# Read/Write parquet file from s3 using R

Tags: r

I want to fetch parquet file from my s3 bucket using R. In my server Spark in not installed.

How to read and write parquet file in R without spark? I am able to read and write data from s3 using different format but not parquet format.

My code is given below -

## Read csv file from s3

```
library(aws.s3)
obj <-get_object("s3://mn-dl.sandbox/Internal Data/test.csv")  
csvcharobj <- rawToChar(obj)  
con <- textConnection(csvcharobj)  
data <- read.csv(file = con)
data1 <-data

#Write csv data directly to s3
s3write_using(data1, FUN = write.csv,
                    bucket = "mn-dl.sandbox",
                    object = "Internal Data/abc.csv")
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: use the `sergeant` package? https://www.r-bloggers.com/create-parquet-files-from-r-data-frames-with-sergeant-apache-drill-a-k-a-make-parquet-files-great-again-in-r/ but it will need apache drill...or alternatively https://github.com/elastacloud/parquetr

Answer (score 2):

Definitely a rookie in using R and AWS, so hopefully this is a universal solution and not just one that worked for me, but here's what I did.

```
install.packages("paws")
install.packages("arrow")

library(paws)
library(arrow)

s3 <- paws::s3(config=list(<your configurations here to give access to s3>))
object <- s3$get_object(Bucket = "path_to_bucket", Key = "file_name.parquet")
data <- object$Body
read_parquet(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have being using the read function, but this write function should work.
Even though you're using the arrow package, you shouldn't need a spark server installed.

```
install.packages("aws.s3")
install.packages("arrow")

library(aws.s3)
library(arrow)

# Read data
obj <-get_object("s3://mn-dl.sandbox/Internal Data/test.csv")  
csvcharobj <- rawToChar(obj)  
con <- textConnection(csvcharobj)  
data <- read.csv(file = con)
data1 <- data

# Write csv data directly to s3
aws.s3::s3write_using(x = data1,
        FUN = arrow::write_parquet,
        bucket = "mn-dl.sandbox",
        object = "Internal Data/abc.csv")
```